# Linking customers with suppliers with given choice

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas

I have an e-commerce application and the logic is simplified as below:

There are 7 colleges with one seat each and there are 4 students who are interested in getting admission.

Here is how to allocate seats...

Akbar will get admission in college 324 because that is his first choice and there is no competition. Now he is out of race and hence 
amar gets shortlisted for college 162 even if he is at second position. Anthony too gets his first choice in college 456 and the student called "shantanu" does not get admission in any college.

Is there a SQL query that will return the expected results?

---

```
drop table college;

create table college (id int not null, primary key (id));
insert into college values (162), (324), (456), (862), (169), (589), (489);

drop table students;
create table students (name varchar(255), marks int, first_pref int, second_pref int,third_pref int);
insert into students values ('shantanu', 67, 162, 324,456);
insert into students values ('amar', 98, 162, 862, 169);
insert into students values ('akbar', 99, 324, 162, 589);
insert into students values ('anthony', 76, 456, 489, 589);

select * from students;
+----------+-------+------------+-------------+------------+
| name     | marks | first_pref | second_pref | third_pref |
+----------+-------+------------+-------------+------------+
| shantanu |    67 |        162 |         324 |        456 |
| amar     |    98 |        162 |         862 |        169 |
| akbar    |    99 |        324 |         162 |        589 |
| anthony  |    76 |        456 |         489 |        589 |
+----------+-------+------------+-------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select name, marks, ( case 
when first_pref=162 then 1 
when second_pref = 162 then 2 
when third_pref = 162 then 3 else 0 
end ) as mypref from students having mypref > 0
order by   marks desc;
+----------+-------+--------+
| name     | marks | mypref |
+----------+-------+--------+
| akbar    |    99 |      2 |
| amar     |    98 |      1 |
| shantanu |    67 |      1 |
+----------+-------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select name, marks, ( case
when first_pref=324 then 1
when second_pref = 324 then 2
when third_pref = 324 then 3 else 0
end ) as mypref from students having mypref > 0
order by  marks desc;
+----------+-------+--------+
| name     | marks | mypref |
+----------+-------+--------+
| akbar    |    99 |      1 |
| shantanu |    67 |      2 |
+----------+-------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select name, marks, ( case
when first_pref=456 then 1
when second_pref = 456 then 2
when third_pref = 456 then 3 else 0
end ) as mypref from students having mypref > 0
order by  marks desc;
+----------+-------+--------+
| name     | marks | mypref |
+----------+-------+--------+
| anthony  |    76 |      1 |
| shantanu |    67 |      3 |
+----------+-------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The expected output is something like this...

```
Student_name college_id
akbar 324
amar 162
anthony 456
shantanu NULL
```

Comment: Is this not procedural - because we first have to eliminate Akbar

Answer (score 1):

```
select name,id from students,college, (case

when first_pref,second_pref,third_pref is not null then mypref
(case
first_pref,second_pref,third_pref == null
end)
else null
end)

as mypref;
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain your answer a bit? Popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the preferred choice of the students with a `case` :

```
select name,
       (case when first_pref  is not null then first_pref
             when second_pref is not null then second_pref
             when third_pref  is not null then third_pref
             else null
        end) as mypref
from students;
```